# Vue 3.2 - Prop object in a prop object

Tags: vue.js

I have a component that builds exercices and series for a workout.
In the Workout vue I call the component and pass multiple props to build the workout as I want.

For exemple :

```
<WorkoutComponent
Exercices=[
{exName: 'Exercice 1',
exDescription: 'The description...',
nbSeries: 6},
{exName: 'Exercice 2',
exDescription: 'Another description...',
nbSeries: 3}]/>
```

It works fine but when I want to build antoher workout using the same exercices I have to enter the description again (and other fields that I don't show here).

**I want to use just the name of the exercice. The other fields would be called from elsewhere (another prop ? a file ?).**

It would look like this (some fields would be completed automatically, such as the description):

```
<WorkoutComponent
Exercices=[Exercice 1,
nbSeries: 6},
{exName: 'Exercice 2',
nbSeries: 3}]/>
```

I tried to insert a prop in the prop like so:

```
<WorkoutComponent
Exercices=[{{exList.Exercice1}},
nbSeries: 6},
{exName: {{exList.Exercice2}},
nbSeries: 3}]/>
```

Tried with exList imported as a .json or a .js but it didn't work.

What could I do ?

Comment: hey mate, did you try to set default values for props?

Answer (score 0):

Anything you bind to a prop should be a valid JavaScript expression.
This is not a valid JavaScript expression:

```
[{{exList.Exercice1}},
nbSeries: 6},
{exName: {{exList.Exercice2}},
nbSeries: 3}]
```

I think you mixed up Vue's text interpolation binding syntax with props binding.
So, your prop binding should look like this:

```
<WorkoutComponent
    :Exercices="[
        {
            exName: exList.Exercice1,
            nbSeries: 6
        },
        {
            exName: exList.Exercice2,
            nbSeries: 3
        }
    ]"
/>
```

On a side note, you should maintain the `Exercises` prop value in a `computed()` or `ref()` to avoid cluttering template.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I have my exercices list in a ts file :

```
const exercices = [
  {
    "exercice":'DIPS',
    "image":'DIPS.png',
    "muscles":'...', 
    "instructions":'...'
  },
  {
    "exercice":'PUSHUPS',
    "image":'PUSHUPS.png',
    "muscles":'...', 
    "instructions":'...'
  }]
export default exercices
```

In my vue I import the file and assign exercices to const :

```
import exercices from '@/components/ExercicesList';

const DIPS = exercices.find(DIPS => DIPS.exercice === 'DIPS');
const PUSHUPS = exercices.find(PUSHUPS => PUSHUPS.exercice === 'PUSHUPS');
```

Then I use it in my props like this :

```
<WorkoutComponent workout="Workout 1" :exercices="[
            {
              exercice: DIPS?.exercice, 
              series:6, 
              image: DIPS?.image, 
              muscles: DIPS?.muscles, 
              instructions: DIPS?.instructions,
              timer_duration: 25
            },
            {
              exercice:PUSHUPS?.exercice, 
              series:3,
              image:PUSHUPS?.image, 
              muscles:PUSHUPS?.muscles, 
              instructions:PUSHUPS?.instructions, 
              timer_duration: 25
            }]
```

It works now :)